# Twitter Bootstrap and ReCaptcha

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, recaptcha

I'm using the basic Twitter Bootstrap .less files as the base styling of a ASP.NET MVC4 website.  I've added a ReCaptcha to a registration page, using the Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha class.  Simplified example:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="@Url.Content("~/scripts/less/style.less")" />
</head>

@ReCaptcha.GetHtml()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: jumbled ReCaptcha]

If I go in with the Chrome dev tools or firebug and remove the twitter bootstrap less, I get the expected ReCaptcha:

[image: good ReCaptcha]

Of course, this nukes all the other styling of the site, which is not desirable.  Has anyone else experienced this, and are there any solutions, short of manually changing the bootstrap classes to add exceptions for the ReCaptcha classes?

Comment: If you post a version that others could play with, that would be helpful in providing you a more specific answer. Otherwise the generic answer is, You need to add some narrow selectors to your CSS (not to Bootstrap) which override whatever Bootstrap might be applying to cause it to go haywire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out now...  In the custom .less file for our site, we had added the following rule to all table elements to fix the layout on a different table element:

```
table th, table td { overflow: hidden; }
```

Adding another rule specific to the ReCaptcha generated html resolved the issue for us:

```
#recaptcha_table{ table-layout: auto; }
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what fixed it for me. Using Bootstrap 2.3.2 in a MVC 4 web app. I added the following css after all other CSS.

```
.recaptchatable * {
    border: 0 !important;
}

body {
    line-height: normal !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like [meffect](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572465/meffect)'s answer here but as I'm using scripted css files that changes my other layouts in bootstrap. Making a slight change and moving the `line-height` property inside `.recaptchatable` solved it for me:

```
.recaptchatable * {
    border: 0 !important;
    line-height: normal !important; }
```

May help someone.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
#recaptcha_widget_div{
     .recaptchatable img{
         max-width: auto;
     }

     input{
         line-height: initial;
         height: auto;
     }
 }
```